# Thymeleaf Model Updating onclick()

Tags: model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am looking to update a filter thymeleaf model attribute so that we don't have to reach out to the backend.  However, it seems that no matter what I do it doesn't update it.  The click doesn't do anything.  Is there something I am missing?  I have tried #, *, @, and $.  None of these seem to work.

Based on what I'm seeing from the error messages I think that the model is immutable and cannot be updated.  Could someone confirm or deny this?

Thanks,

Original

```
<a th:onclick="#{filter='all'}">All</a>
```

Comment: are you having any error on the browser's console when you're clicking on the button. check your browser's console one time.

Comment: Thymeleaf is server side only.  You have to use JavaScript if you want something like this.

Comment: @Metroids can you use a javascript variable in an thymeleaf html tag?

Comment: No.  You can generate JavaScript code with Thymeleaf, but once Thymeleaf has been rendered, there is no modifying the Thymeleaf model without going back to the server and rendering the page again.